# AngularJS 1.4 post failed because browser doesn't add auto generated Headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I am new to angularJS, our team just have very old project uses angularJS 1.4, the task sounds easy, just to add three custom header when we request to backend to tracking request
this is original header(success):

```
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
113
Content-Type:
application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:
granite161bcmino-app-ctec-dev03.enwd.co.sa.charterlab.com:8281
Origin:
https://11.11.11.11
Referer:
https://11.11.11.11/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
cross-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

this is once I add custom header(all failed):

```
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Application:
app
Content-Type:
application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer:
https://11.11.11.11/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"macOS"
Trace-Id:
stestidddddddd
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
User-Id:
testuseridddd
```

extra context:
backend server run as java in weblogic
option check is 200 ok, actuall endpoint doesn't need any header
here is the actual endpoint:

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/xxxxx")
    public Response xxxxx(String jsonbody) {
        return something;
    }
```

here is the option endpoint:

```
    @OPTIONS
    @PermitAll
    @Path("/xxxxx")
    public Response xxxxx() {
        return Response
            .status(200)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD").build();

    }
```

there are only 2 interceptor for whole app, exception the one I add, another one do nothing to headers

POSTMAN request will success with HOST and content-Length

please give me hit, I have been search online for whole week, but not solved anything, just learned this old version a lot

I have tried 1, directly add config when

```
$[http.post](https://http.post)(url, data, config)
```

2, add a interceptor to add the  modify the config. both indeed changed the header, but the request will failed because of once I changed the header, browser will not add `Content-Length` and `Host` header automatically, and if I want to manually set it using methods I mentioned above, it will gives error in debugger tool

```
angular.js:10458 Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length
```

etc.

Comment: please share angularjs code

Comment: @Parth M. Dave Thank you!, problem has been solved. it was because of backend server didn't handle OPTIONS request well

Answer (score 1):

Found out it is not a code problem, it is due to the HTTP2 protocol. It sends a preflight request to the backend server, and since JAX-RS, doesn't provide an auto CORS check, we need to make the response of that preflight contain the header:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "header you want"
```